# traefik ingress StripPrefix

Tags: kubernetes, routes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik, traefik-ingress

Using traefik as the ingress controller and looking for a way to stripping path prefixing. as these prefixed path section is "forwarded" to the service unless the service is also listening on a same path, the service will hit a 404. it was not very clear on the docs how to remove the forwarded paths, any pointers?

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: azure-vote-route
  namespace: azure-vote
spec:
  rules:
    - host: <>.<>.cloudapp.azure.com
      http:
        paths:
        # - path: /
        #   pathType: Prefix
        #   backend:
        #     service:
        #       name: azure-vote-front
        #       port:
        #         number: 80
        - path: /foo
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: azure-vote-front
              port:
                number: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

found the answers

option 1
kind: Ingress
and using a Middleware from traefik to strip the prefix. and this middleware is refereed using an annotation on the Ingress definition
`<namespace-of-middlewear>-<name-of-middlewear>`

eg

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: ingress-stripprefix
  namespace: azure-vote
spec:
  stripPrefix:
    prefixes:
      - /foo

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-a
  namespace: azure-vote
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: azure-vote-ingress-stripprefix@kubernetescrd
spec:
  rules:
    - host: <>.<>.cloudapp.azure.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /foo
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name:  azure-vote-front
                port:
                  number: 80
```

option 2
kind: IngressRoute  (which is a traefik specific ingress implementation.)

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: ingressroute-middle
  namespace: azure-vote
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - match: Host(`<>.cloudapp.azure.com`) && PathPrefix(`/test`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: azure-vote-front
          port: 80
      middlewares:
        - name: testmiddle
    - match: Host(`<>.cloudapp.azure.com`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: azure-vote-front
          port: 80
      middlewares:
        - name: testmiddle
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: testmiddle
  namespace: azure-vote
spec:
  stripPrefix:
    prefixes:
      - /test
```